# How to add new Fingerprint using our own app?

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics

i have Searched All over Internet about how to add new Fingerprint using our own app, but i am unable to find anything, i have also searched on stackoverflow about this and i found some Same Questions to but no one has answered about this correctly, So i have decided to ask this question one more time.

I have successfully Completed the Authentication through Fingerprint
but know i want to add multiple fingerprints to my app
I am making an app where new users Registered first they enter there name,address,emailID,Age and Fingerprint. all the data stored in MYSQLI 
after that when the new user Successfully registered, when the same person tries to login, the first thing he should do is to scan his finger when the scan successfully all the Details which he mentioned while Registration will shows up 
i mean his Name,addess,EmailID,Age

So, This is what i want it is similar to Bio-metric fingerprint reader but i want to do this with Mobile fingerprint scanner can anyone help me??
I have done this 
[Fingerprint](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.java#258)   but no success Help me out thank you

Comment: you can use phone finger print to verify your app.it will use your phone fingerlock

Comment: In addition to the answer below regarding enrollment of fingerprints, Android's fingerprint API only lets you know if a fingerprint authentication matched _any of_ the fingerprints enrolled on the device. It doesn't let you know _which_ fingerprint it matched.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a fingerprint under the direction of the app with a mobile device built-in fingerprint reader/framework is **NOT POSSIBLE**:

From [Android Source Site:Security:Authentication:Enrollment](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/#enrollment):

> On first boot of the device after a factory reset, all authenticators are prepared to receive credential enrollments from the user. **A user must initially enroll a PIN/pattern/password with Gatekeeper.** This initial enrollment creates a randomly generated, 64-bit User SID (user secure identifier) that serves as an identifier for the user and as a binding token for the user's cryptographic material. This User SID is cryptographically bound to the user's password; successful authentications to Gatekeeper result in AuthTokens that contain the User SID for that password.

The key part is:

**A user must initially enroll a PIN/pattern/password with Gatekeeper.**

That means that the owner/user must enroll a PIN which will be eventually associated with the Fingerprint.

> A user who wants to change a credential must present an existing credential. If an existing credential is verified successfully, the User SID associated with the existing credential is transferred to the new credential, enabling the user to keep accessing keys after changing a credential. If a user does not present an existing credential, the new credential is enrolled with a fully random User SID. The user can access the device, but keys created under the old User SID are permanently lost. This is known as an untrusted enroll.

As you continue reading you read:

*If a user does not present an existing credential, the new credential is enrolled with a fully random User SID. The user can access the device, but keys created under the old User SID are permanently lost. This is known as an untrusted enroll.*

And perhaps you hope that your app can invoke an *untrusted enroll*

**BUT**

> **Under normal circumstances, the Android framework does not allow an untrusted enroll, so most users won't ever see this functionality.** However, forcible password resets, either by a device administrator or an attacker, may cause this to occur.

So apps are only allowed to know if a user has *Authenticated* a preregistered Fingerprint via [FingerprintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager) or [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt)

**What can I do**

You'll have to look into external fingerprint readers to achieve what you want.
Possibly a Custom ROM would be another path to investigate, but would require a number of changes as the expectation is that each Fingerprint be cryptographically associated with PIN as well (see first quoted paragraph above).

Comment: okay and what if i have a Bio-metric device, then i have to use the same FingerprintManager  function to get multiple users fingerprint..??

Comment: If you are using a stock/off-the-shelf Android device, use the SDK for the external Biometric device to both register and authenticate multiple users and **not** use the Android FingerprintManager, as you won't be going through the secure *trusted* part of Android

Comment: okay I am using Morpho Mso1300 E2 Fingerprint Biometric Scanner (Red & Black) Time & Attendance  (Fingerprint). Now i need its SDK as you said, i found Morpho_API.DLL file and nothing more, how to integrate Morpho SDK to my app, recently i have added U.are U 4500 Dependency in my app but i dont have that device i have Morpho, can you help or tell me where i get the Morpho Dependency...? Thank you

Comment: Search for your product/manufacturer and ask the vendor for SDK & Documentation. Otherwise create a new question specifically about your issue, but should ask vendor first as it is their SDK.